# C++ Template Linked List Linker Error

Tags: c++, templates, visual-studio-2012, linked-list, linker-errors

I think I'm improperly using my template but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. It's like the template linked list can't figure out that it needs to use my Term class.

**theList->insert(tempPolynomial); is the line of code, located at the end of function.cpp, that causes the linker error!**

Here are the exact errors from Visual Studio 2012:

- error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "bool __cdecl operator<(class Term,class LinkedList)" (??M@YA_NVTerm@@V?$LinkedList@VTerm@@@@@Z) referenced in function "public: void __thiscall LinkedList::insert(class Term)" (?insert@?$LinkedList@VTerm@@@@QAEXVTerm@@@Z)  C:\Users\Michael\Documents\Magic Briefcase\champlain\courseWork\dataStructures\pa2\pa2\functions.obj
- error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals C:\Users\Michael\Documents\Magic Briefcase\champlain\courseWork\dataStructures\pa2\Debug\pa2.exe

header.h

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

#include "linkedList.h"
#include "term.h"

void loadPolynomial(string expression, LinkedList<Term> *theList);
```

functions.cpp

```
#include "header.h"


void loadPolynomial(string expression, LinkedList<Term> *theList)
{
    Term tempPolynomial;

    string varDelimiter = "x";
    string posDelimiter = "+";
    string negDelimiter = "-";
    string token = "";

    double coefficient;
    double exponent;

    bool isNeg;

    while(expression.length() > 0)
    {
        isNeg = false;

        if(expression.substr(0, 1) == "+")
        {
            expression.erase(0, 1);
        }

        else if(expression.substr(0, 1) == "-")
        {
            isNeg = true;
            expression.erase(0, 1);
        }

        //Get the coefficient
        token = expression.substr(0, expression.find(varDelimiter));
        //Remove the coefficient and variable from the string leaving only the exponent
        expression.erase(0, expression.find(varDelimiter) + varDelimiter.length());
        //Convert and put token's coeficient into a double
        coefficient = atof(token.c_str());

        if(isNeg = true)
        {
            coefficient = coefficient * -1;
        }

        //Put the coefficient value into the tempPolynomial
        tempPolynomial.setCoefficient(coefficient);

        //If posDelimiter has a smaller length then it is the beginning of the next expression
        if(expression.find(posDelimiter) < expression.find(negDelimiter))
        {
            //Get the exponent
            token = expression.substr(0, expression.find(posDelimiter));
            //Remove the exponent but leave the + 
            expression.erase(0, expression.find(varDelimiter));
            //Convert and put token's coeficient into a double
            exponent = atof(token.c_str());
        }

        else
        {
            //Get the exponent
            token = expression.substr(0, expression.find(posDelimiter));
            //Remove the exponent but leave the +
            expression.erase(0, expression.find(varDelimiter));
            //Convert and put token's coeficient into a double
            exponent = atof(token.c_str());
        }

        //Put the exponent value into the tempPolynomial
        tempPolynomial.setExponent(exponent);

        //Intert the first term into the linked list
        theList->insert(tempPolynomial);
    }
}
```

linkedList.h

```
#ifndef LINKED_LIST_H
#define LINKED_LIST_H

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

template <class T>
class LinkedList
{
private:
    T mData;
    LinkedList<T> *mNext;

public:
    LinkedList();
    LinkedList(T data);
    ~LinkedList();

    T getData();
    LinkedList<T> *getNext();

    void setData(T data);

    void display();
    void insert(T data);
    bool isExist(T data);
    void remove(T data);

    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream &output, LinkedList<T> obj);

    bool operator==(T right);
    friend bool operator==(T left, LinkedList<T> right);

    bool operator!=(T right);
    friend bool operator!=(T left, LinkedList<T> right);

    bool operator>(T right);
    friend bool operator>(T left, LinkedList<T> right);

    bool operator<(T right);
    friend bool operator<(T left, LinkedList<T> right);
};



template <class T>
LinkedList<T>::LinkedList()
{
    mNext = NULL;
    mData = T();
}



template <class T>
LinkedList<T>::LinkedList(T data)
{
    mNext = NULL;
    mData = data;
}



template <class T>
LinkedList<T>::~LinkedList()
{
    LinkedList<T> *tempNode;

    tempNode = mNext;

    while(tempNode != NULL)
    {
        mNext = tempNode->mNext;
        tempNode->mNext = NULL;

        delete tempNode;

        tempNode = mNext;
    }
}



template <class T>
T LinkedList<T>::getData()
{
    return mData;
}



template <class T>
LinkedList<T> *LinkedList<T>::getNext()
{
    return mNext;
}



template <class T>
void LinkedList<T>::setData(T data)
{
    mData = data;
}



template <class T>
void LinkedList<T>::display()
{
    LinkedList<T> *tempNode;

    tempNode = mNext;

    while(tempNode != NULL)
    {
        cout << tempNode->mData << endl;

        tempNode = tempNode->mNext;
    }
}



template <class T>
void LinkedList<T>::insert(T data)
{
    LinkedList<T> *previousNode;
    LinkedList<T> *tempNode;
    LinkedList<T> *newNode;

    newNode = new LinkedList(data);

    if(mNext == NULL)
    {
        mNext = newNode;
    }

    else
    {
        previousNode = mNext;
        tempNode = mNext;

        while(tempNode != NULL && tempNode->mData < data)
        {
            previousNode = tempNode;
            tempNode = tempNode->mNext;
        }

        if(tempNode == mNext)
        {
            newNode->mNext = mNext;
            mNext = newNode;
        }

        else
        {
            previousNode->mNext = newNode;
            newNode->mNext = tempNode;
        }
    }
}



template <class T>
bool LinkedList<T>::isExist(T data)
{
    LinkedList<T> *tempNode;
    bool exist = false;

    tempNode = mNext;

    while(tempNode != NULL)
    {
        if(tempNode->mData == data)
        {
            exist = true;

            break;
        }

        tempNode = tempNode->mNext;
    }

    return exist;
}



template <class T>
void LinkedList<T>::remove(T data)
{
    LinkedList<T> *tempNode;
    LinkedList<T> *previousNode;

    if(isExist(data) == false)
    {
        return;
    }

    tempNode = mNext;
    previousNode = mNext;

    while(tempNode->mData != data)
    {
        previousNode = tempNode;
        tempNode = tempNode->mNext;
    }

    if(tempNode == mNext)
    {
        mNext = tempNode->mNext;
        tempNode->mNext = NULL;
    }

    else
    {
        if(tempNode->mNext == NULL)
        {
            previousNode->mNext = NULL;
        }

        else
        {
            previousNode->mNext = tempNode->mNext;
            tempNode->mNext = NULL;
        }
    }

    delete tempNode;
}



template <class T>
ostream& operator<<(ostream &output, LinkedList<T> obj)
{
    output << obj.mData;

    return output;
}



template <class T>
bool LinkedList<T>::operator==(T right)
{
    return mData == right;
}



template <class T>
bool operator==(T left, LinkedList<T> right)
{
    return left == right.mData;
}



template <class T>
bool LinkedList<T>::operator!=(T right)
{
    return mData != right;
}



template <class T>
bool operator!=(T left, LinkedList<T> right)
{
    return left != right.mData;
}



template <class T>
bool LinkedList<T>::operator>(T right)
{
    return mData > right;
}



template <class T>
bool operator>(T left, LinkedList<T> right)
{
    return left > right.mData;
}



template <class T>
bool LinkedList<T>::operator<(T right)
{
    return mData < right;
}



template <class T>
bool operator<(T left, LinkedList<T> right)
{
    return left < right.mData;
}

#endif
```

term.h

```
#ifndef TERM_H
#define TERM_H

class Term
{
private:
    double mCoefficient;
    double mExponent; 

public:
    Term();
    Term(double coefficient, double exponent);
    ~Term();

    double getCoefficient();
    double getExponent();
    void setCoefficient(double coefficient);
    void setExponent(double exponent);
};

#endif
```

Comment: You declare your friended operators but you don't *define* them anyway. So... define them?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean as all functions in the linkedList class are implemented. The linker error occurs due to this line of code: theList->insert(tempPolynomial);

Comment: The linker claims this:`bool __cdecl operator<(class Term,class LinkedList)` is not found. `insert()` is the *caller*. I can see the decl at the bottom of the header file, so I'm now not sure why your template isn't being expanded. In `insert()` this: `tempNode->mData < data` is where it is pulled in.

Comment: In my main function the LinkedList is initialized as a type Term, which would make data have a type of Term too. So shouldn't it be successfully pulled in?

Comment: Are you saying they have to be overloaded to work specifically with the Term class? Is this something I'd overload/do in the Term class? Also thanks for your help so far.

Comment: Duh. that's exactly what it is. (and you found it, whether you knew it or not). `Term` doesn't have a `operator <`. it needs one.

Comment: I'm writing up the answer now. It will make sense.

Comment: So I'll rewrite `bool operator<(T right);` and `friend bool operator<(T left, LinkedList<T> right);` and make them part of the Term class correct?

Comment: I don't have anything passing by reference like that and there is no `bool Term::operator <(const Term&)'. Also why are you passing by reference?

Comment: See the answer below for why you need the operator. Regarding passing by reference: depending on the type (objects yes, integrals like `int` no) it is much more efficient to pass by const-reference for things like this, as it avoids creating mountains of temporaries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Term class needs an lesser comparator. Either of these will do:

In the term class as a member:

```
bool operator <(const Term&) const;
```

Or a free operator function:

```
bool operator <(const Term& left, const Term& right);
```

Why? Because `LinkedList<T>::insert(T val)` invokes the following:

```
while(tempNode != NULL && tempNode->mData < data)
```

Both `tempNode->mData` and `data` are of type `Term` with your template expansion. But there is no `operator <` (either member function or free function) that compares two `Term` objects for "lesser".

I'm not sure how you want to sort them (I'd likely sort them on exponent first, then coefficient of the exponents are the same). I leave that up to you, but you need the operator regardless.

**Example** (in the `Term` class as a member)

```
bool operator <(const Term& rhs) const
{
    return (mCoefficient < rhs.mCoefficient ||
           (!(rhs.mCoefficient < mCoefficient) == && mExponent < rhs.mExponent));
}
```

**Example II** (free operator; NOT a member of `Term`)

```
bool operator <(const Term& lhs, const Term& rhs)
{
    return (lhs.getCoefficient() < rhs.getCoefficient() ||
           (!(rhs.getCoefficient() < lhs.getCoefficient()) == && 
             lhs.getExponent() < rhs.getExponent()));
}
```

Note: if this is friended to `Term` you can access the members directly rather than going through their getter functions (which, by the way, should be declared `const` as they make no modifications to the `Term` object on which they're being called).

Comment: Thank you so much it worked and it makes much more sense now. Though I still don't get the "free operator" concept. Is it a generic function that overrides the standard < operator or what?

Comment: @user2045519 I'll add one to the answer and you can see the difference. It will be obvious.

Comment: Everything makes so much sense now! Thank you so much!